# Dapper MultiQuery only returning the first match

Tags: sql, .net-core, dapper

I have a query to get a single document:-

```sql
SELECT      doc.Id
            ,doc.Type
            ,doc.Name
            ,doc.Description
            ,doc.File
            ,doc.CreatedAt
            ,doc.UpdatedAt
            ,dl.LabelId
            ,l.Name
            ,l.Description
            ,dc.DocumentId
            ,dc.ProfileId
            ,dc.Role
FROM        Documents as doc
LEFT JOIN   DocumentCollaborators as dc
    ON      doc.Id = dc.DocumentId
LEFT JOIN   DocumentLabels as dl
    ON      doc.Id = dl.DocumentId
LEFT JOIN   Labels as l
    ON      dl.LabelId = l.Id
WHERE       doc.Id =  @Id
```

I query this with Dapper as follows:

```cs
var documents = await connection.QueryAsync<DocumentDto, LabelDto, CollaboratorDto, DocumentDto>(
            GetDocumentSql,
            (doc, label, collaborator) => {
                if (label.LabelId != Guid.Empty) // empty guid means no label
                {
                    doc.Labels.Add(label);
                }
                if (collaborator.ProfileId != Guid.Empty) // empty guid means no collaborator
                {
                    doc.Collaborators.Add(collaborator);
                }
                return doc;
            }, 
            new
            {
                Id = documentId.ToString()
            },
            splitOn: "LabelId,DocumentId");
```

My DTOs are as follows:

```cs
public abstract class BaseDocumentDto
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public int Type { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string File { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class DocumentDto : BaseDocumentDto
{
    public IList<LabelDto> Labels { get; set; } = new List<LabelDto>();
    public IList<CollaboratorDto> Collaborators { get; set; } = new List<CollaboratorDto>();
}

public class LabelDto
{
    public Guid LabelId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public string Description { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }
}

public class CollaboratorDto
{
    public Guid ProfileId { get; set; }
    public int Role { get; set; }
}
```

If I try and run this where the database has more than one record for either labels or collaborators then I only get the first one in the returned `DocumentDTO`.

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**
Here is some example data I get back

| Id | Type | Name | Description | File | CreatedAt | UpdatedAt | LabelId | Name | Description | DocumentId | ProfileId | Role |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 1 | Test Document for debugging | This document is used for debugging purposes | https://test.document.com | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 023b5c62-0f4d-4937-a7b7-4699b74c1380 | Test Label for debugging 001 | This label is used for debugging purposes | c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 16c20d76-53dc-460f-918a-1d8fedf0e4bb | 1 |
| c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 1 | Test Document for debugging | This document is used for debugging purposes | https://test.document.com | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 023b5c62-0f4d-4937-a7b7-4699b74c1380 | Test Label for debugging 001 | This label is used for debugging purposes | c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 925b6d87-3113-42f7-924a-6da0b8495b44 | 2 |
| c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 1 | Test Document for debugging | This document is used for debugging purposes | https://test.document.com | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 8500eeae-0f27-44ba-97c1-7f2b03f0e273 | Test Label for debugging 002 | This label is used for debugging purposes | c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 16c20d76-53dc-460f-918a-1d8fedf0e4bb | 1 |
| c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 1 | Test Document for debugging | This document is used for debugging purposes | https://test.document.com | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 8500eeae-0f27-44ba-97c1-7f2b03f0e273 | Test Label for debugging 002 | This label is used for debugging purposes | c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 925b6d87-3113-42f7-924a-6da0b8495b44 | 2 |
| c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 1 | Test Document for debugging | This document is used for debugging purposes | https://test.document.com | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | a51eab3d-c23e-4cf0-81a8-4d958069d73f | Test Label for debugging 003 | This label is used for debugging purposes | c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 16c20d76-53dc-460f-918a-1d8fedf0e4bb | 1 |
| c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 1 | Test Document for debugging | This document is used for debugging purposes | https://test.document.com | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | 2021-07-01 00:00:00 | a51eab3d-c23e-4cf0-81a8-4d958069d73f | Test Label for debugging 003 | This label is used for debugging purposes | c255293f-2461-4013-a2a5-ee8827927db5 | 925b6d87-3113-42f7-924a-6da0b8495b44 | 2 |

When I debug the `map` function I see that it gets called for each row. The `doc`, `label`, and `collaborator` objects have their properties mapped properly. However, even though when the function returns the `doc` has been updated when the `map` function gets called again the `doc` object has none of the updates from previous calls.

Comment: *If I try and run this where the database has more than one record for either labels or collaborators then I only get the first one in the returned DocumentDTO*, your DB records mentioned with different `LabelId` and `DocumentId`? Cause in your Dapper query, you are performing grouping by same `LabelId` and `DocumentId`.

Comment: _when the function returns the doc has been updated when the map function gets called again the doc object has none of the updates from previous calls._: No, that's what I'm trying to explain below. You cannot use those variables from line to line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in the end I worked it out. I did the following based on https://www.learndapper.com/relationships

```cs
var documents = await connection.QueryAsync<DocumentDto, LabelDto, CollaboratorDto, DocumentDto>(
            GetDocumentSql,
            (doc, label, collaborator) => {
                if (label is not null && label.LabelId != Guid.Empty) // empty guid means no label
                {
                    doc.Labels.Add(label);
                }
                if (collaborator.ProfileId != Guid.Empty) // empty guid means no collaborator
                {
                    doc.Collaborators.Add(collaborator);
                }
                return doc;
            }, 
            new
            {
                Id = documentId.ToString()
            },
            splitOn: "LabelId,DocumentId");
        
        var result = documents
            .GroupBy(d => d.Id)
            .Select(g =>
        {
            var groupedDocument = g.First();
            groupedDocument.Labels = g.Select(d => d.Labels.Single())
                .GroupBy(l => l.LabelId)
                .Select(l=> l.First())
                .ToList();
            groupedDocument.Collaborators = g.Select(d => d.Collaborators.Single())
                .GroupBy(c => c.ProfileId)
                .Select(c => c.First())
                .ToList();
            return groupedDocument;
        });
```

I am not in love with the catalogue of LINQ, but it does exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do wrong: You assume that the doc you have in the second line in the resultset is the same as in the first line. That is not the case, you get a new `doc` for every line. Instead do like this:

```cs
DocumentDto myDoc = null;
var documents = await connection.QueryAsync<DocumentDto, LabelDto, CollaboratorDto, DocumentDto>(
    GetDocumentSql, (doc, label, collaborator) => 
        {
            if (myDoc is null)
            {
                myDoc = doc;
            }  
            if (label.LabelId != Guid.Empty) // empty guid means no label
            {
                myDoc.Labels.Add(label);
            }
            if (collaborator.ProfileId != Guid.Empty) // empty guid means no collaborator
            {
                myDoc.Collaborators.Add(collaborator);
            }
            return null; // Your data is in myDoc, no need to return anything
        }, 
        new
        {
            Id = documentId.ToString()
        },
        splitOn: "LabelId,DocumentId");
// Go ahead and use myDoc
if (myDoc is null)
{
    // Tell user "No documents found"
}        
else
{
    // Use myDoc as your result here
}
```

Another issue is that you don't need to select DocumentId. The query should look like:

```
SELECT      doc.Id
            ,doc.Type
            ,doc.Name
            ,doc.Description
            ,doc.File
            ,doc.CreatedAt
            ,doc.UpdatedAt
            ,dl.LabelId
            ,l.Name
            ,l.Description
            ,dc.ProfileId
            ,dc.Role
FROM        Documents as doc
LEFT JOIN   DocumentCollaborators as dc
    ON      doc.Id = dc.DocumentId
LEFT JOIN   DocumentLabels as dl
    ON      doc.Id = dl.DocumentId
LEFT JOIN   Labels as l
    ON      dl.LabelId = l.Id
WHERE       doc.Id =  @Id
```

And then your splitOn should be like this:

```cs
        splitOn: "LabelId,ProfileId");
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but if you return null then you get no results at all.

Comment: The result is in myDoc, it doesn't matter what you return.

Comment: While that will work in this instance. It is not how it is documented to work. https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper?tab=readme-ov-file#multi-mapping

Comment: The User/Post example is a one-to-one relation, yours is a one-to-many.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean.